# Ruby - Swapping primary keys of two ActiveRecord instances? Elegantly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, primary-key, swap

Minor question... it's to resolve what is a simple hack and seems *silly* not to fix!

If there are two items of the same class, derived from ActiveRecord, how can I swap their primary keys? The following code works, but look at it!

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :p_key

  def self.swap( a, b )
    return if a.nil? or a.nil?

    # fix this hack!
    temp_1 = a.p_key
    a.p_key = "999999" #these keys cannot ever occur in our software... promise!
    a.p_key.save!
    a.p_key = b.p_key
    b.p_key = temp_2
    b.save!
    a.save!
  end
end
```

**Ugh! It's gross!**

The following code results in an error:

```
 a.p_key, b.p_key = b.p_key, a.p_key
 a.save!
 b.save!
```

Comment: At a higher level, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord (like any other ORM) does not allow to change primary keys. If you will change it somehow, your model instance will refer to a different database record (if it exists).

For example, let's say you have an instance of Item model having primary key 10. If you change any field and save the model, ActiveRecord will generate a SQL statement like `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE id = 10`. This statement will update the database row having id=10.

If you somehow change the primary key to 20, then ActiveRecord will generate a SQL statement like `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE id = 20`. This statement updates a different row (if it exists) keeping the row with id=10 unchanged.

To change primary key, you have to execute a SQL statement like this: `UPDATE my_table SET id = 20 WHERE id = 10`. After that you will need to `reload` your model instances having `id` 10 and 20.

It will be a little bit tricky (however possible, depending on your DB server) to write a SQL statement that swaps primary keys for two database rows. But ActiveRecord will not help you.

Why do you need that? The question looks pretty weird, so I guess that you actually need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to swap key values 1 and 2. In Standard SQL:

```
UPDATE tbl SET keycol = CASE keycol WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 2 THEN 1 END
WHERE keycol IN (1,2);
```

You could also approach the problem the other way and swap the values of every *non-key* column - which of course has the same effect in the end. Here's a way to do it but unfortunately it isn't standard SQL. it works for SQL Server and possibly others but I haven't tested it elsewhere. To achieve the same thing in Standard SQL I think you would have to create a view in place of the derived table subquery.

```
UPDATE t SET x1 = x2, y1 = y2, z1 = z2
FROM
(
  SELECT t1.keycol keycol1, t2.keycol keycol2,
  t1.x x1, t1.y y1, t1.z z1, t2.x x2, t2.y y2, t2.z z2
  FROM tbl t1, tbl t2
  WHERE (t1.keycol = 1 AND t2.keycol = 2)
  OR (t1.keycol = 2 AND t2.keycol = 1)
) t;
```